# I loose LAN networking features when I prioritize WiFi or lan on server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I’m trying to get my server a dedicated internet connection while’s my other systems can still access it via lan. I tried to simply connect a WiFi network to it while’s keeping the lan connected but discovered that windows always prioritized LAN connections over WiFi.so I used the metric system to change the priority values of both my wireless and lan adaptors, prioritizing my WiFi over my lan. It works but now anytime my WiFi if prioritized my server can’t be accessed or discovered by any of my systems on the lan, although the server is still connected to the lan. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the output of cmd `route print`, the IP addresses of both interfaces, and the IP of one of your other LAN devices to your question?